# Set state in component from input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to set the state of an input in my component, and use it in my app.js. How am I able to do this with props? I tried `onChangeText={(tips) => this.setState({comment})}` but I only get undefined..

```
const Comments = (props) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
<Input style={styles.field}
  autoCorrect={false}
  autoCapitalize="none"
  onChangeText={props.onChangeText}
  placeholder="Skriv en kommentar..."
/>
<Button rounded style={styles.button} onPress={() => props.addComment(props.id)}>
  <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Kommenter</Text>
</Button>
</View>
  )
}
export { Comments };
```

In my app.js I have:

My app.js

```
    export default class Home extends Component {
    constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      comment: '',
    }
   newComment = (comment) => {
      change = (comment) => this.setState(comment)
      alert(comment)
   }
  renderItem = ({ item, index }) => {
   return (
       <Comments
          addComment={this.newComment}
          comments={this.state.comment}
          onChangeText={this.change}
        />
   )
  }
 }
```

Comment: You'll want to read up on context binding in React

Comment: I think you meant: `onChangeText={(comment) => this.setState({comment})}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant use `setState` in a **stateless component**.
You need to pass a `handler` from the parent function that changes the values based on the `onChangeText`

### Parent

```
change = (comment) => this.setState({comment})

<Comments
   comments={this.state.comment}
   onChangeText={this.change}
/>
```

### Child

```
const Comments = (props) => {
  return (

    <Input style={styles.field}
      ...// other stuff
      onChangeText={props.onChangeText}
    />

    </View>
  )
}
```

Comment: I am getting 'undefined' from this. `newComment = (comment) => {alert(comment)}` I added the handler right above <Comments /> and in my Component the State is Comments:''

Comment: What is the exact error that you get? Which of the following shows undefined?

Comment: I updated my code above. It is no error, only undefined when I click on newComment to check if it is stored

Comment: Add `change` method as a separate handler outside of `newComment`

Comment: Now i get `setState(...): takes an object of state variables to update or a function which returns an object of state variables.`

Comment: `this.setState({comment})`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179973/discussion-between-vemund-and-pritish-vaidya).

Answer (score 3):

I strongly suggest you read the official [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hello-world.html) first. Not the native one, the regular one. Because it is clear that you are struggling with basic stuff.

- If you want to use a prop in child component, you must pass it from the parent.
- If you want to change a parent's state in a child component, you must pass a handler function to the child as a prop.

You are only passing `comments` to your `Comments` component but does not pass a handler function. So, you can't add a comment here with an undefined handler.

I'm providing a working example with React. Here, We are holding the comments in `App`'s state and mapping the comments to a separate `Comment` component. This component is a stateless one and just rendering the comment that is passed to it. Also, it has a button to remove the provided comment.

For adding a new comment we are holding an input in the `App` component. This input changes an `input` state. When we want to add a new comment, we are creating a new one using this `input` and assign an `id` to it. Then add it to our state.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    comments: [],
    input: "",
    currentId: 0
  };

  handleInputChange = e => {
    const { value } = e.target;
    this.setState({ input: value });
  };

  renderComments = () => (
    <div>
      <h2>Comments:</h2>
      {this.state.comments.map(comment => (
        <Comment
          key={comment.id}
          comment={comment}
          removeComment={this.removeComment}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );

  addNewComment = () => {
    const { currentId, input } = this.state;
    const newComment = {
      id: currentId + 1,
      text: input
    };

    this.setState(prevState => ({
      comments: [...prevState.comments, newComment],
      currentId: prevState.currentId + 1,
      input: ""
    }));
  };

  removeComment = comment => {
    const { comments } = this.state;
    const newComments = comments.filter(el => el.id !== comment.id);

    this.setState({ comments: newComments });
  };

  render() {
    const { comments, input } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Add Comment</p>
        <input value={input} onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
        <button onClick={this.addNewComment}>Add new comment</button>
        <hr />
        {!comments.length ? <p>No comments yet</p> : this.renderComments()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const Comment = props => {
  const { comment, removeComment } = props;
  const handleRemove = () => removeComment(comment);

  return (
    <div style={{ border: "1px solid gray" }}>
      <p>Id: {comment.id}</p>
      <p>Text: {comment.text}</p>
      <button onClick={handleRemove}>Remove comment</button>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: This is a great answer. Learned much from this. However in my case it is the other way around. The comment component is where the input goes and information goes back to the App.

Comment: Input can be in the child, this is normal. But again you will use the parent's state and update it with a handler. So, information should not go to the child to parent. React is unidirectional.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have a parent component `< MyContainer/>` and an standard `< Input/>` component. Set the state of the parent with the initial value of the input. Something like this:

```
class MyContainer extends Component{
    state ={ value: '' }

    onChangeTextHandler = e =>{
        this.setState({value: e.target.value})
    }
}
```

Now just pass the reference to this function via props to your `< Input/>` component: 
`< Input onChangeText={this.onChangeTextHandler} value={this.state.value}/>`

Take a deeper look at [Two-way data binding](https://reactjs.org/docs/two-way-binding-helpers.html)